Why does the initialization operation of @PostConstruct execute before schema.sql?
I am writing a java program using spring-boot. At first I am using schema.sql to initialise the database. It contains table building statements.
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products (
  id varchar(200),
  tid varchar(200),
  price numeric,
  category varchar(20),
  quantity INTEGER,
  product_name varchar(200),
  stock INTEGER,
  img varchar(200)
);

Now I want to implement a feature where the program automatically crawls data from the web and inserts it into a table in the database after startup. I tried to use the @PostConstruct, but the execution result shows that the table 'products' does not exist, indicating that the @PostConstruct method executes before the schema.sql
public class PosServiceImp implements PosService {
...

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() throws IOException{
        List<Product> JDProducts = parseJD("java");   // The data crawled from web
        for (Product product:JDProducts){
            addProduct(product);
            
        }
    }
...
}

The error message is as follows
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "PRODUCTS" not found (this database is empty); SQL statement:
select p1_0.id,p1_0.category,p1_0.img,p1_0.product_name,p1_0.price,p1_0.quantity,p1_0.stock,p1_0.tid from products p1_0 where p1_0.id=? [42104-224]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:514)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:489)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:223)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:199)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.getTableOrViewNotFoundDbException(Parser.java:8051)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.getTableOrViewNotFoundDbException(Parser.java:8035)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:8024)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.readTablePrimary(Parser.java:1788)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableReference(Parser.java:2268)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectFromPart(Parser.java:2718)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:2824)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryPrimary(Parser.java:2708)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryTerm(Parser.java:2564)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryExpressionBody(Parser.java:2543)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryExpressionBodyAndEndOfQuery(Parser.java:2536)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryExpression(Parser.java:2529)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQuery(Parser.java:2498)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:627)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:592)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:564)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:483)
        at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareLocal(SessionLocal.java:639)
        at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareCommand(SessionLocal.java:559)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1166)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:93)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:316)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:327)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement(HikariProxyConnection.java)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:153)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:183)
        ... 115 common frames omitted

Why is this happening? Is there any other way to achieve the operation I need?

Have you verified that the schema.sql is applied at all (i.e. even if we remove the @PostConsntruct)? --- Please provide a [MRE], e.g. in form of a git repository.

Yes, I'm sure the schema.sql is working , and the products table can be accessed correctly if the @PostConstruct method is removed.
I created a new github repository and placed the simplified code in it, here is the link:https://github.com/Baykin5/tempRepository.git

Please avoid checking in the target repository. I'll have a look.

Remove spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true from the application.properties.

It solved my problem, very helpful.I use the configuration without understanding.
